# Inno CustomPage with full size background picture

Tags: inno-setup

Why my bitmap is not full screen size?

```
BitmapImage1 := TBitmapImage.Create(Page);
```

Its somehow made smaller by INNO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom, you must set the `Parent`,`Align` and `Stretch` properties to fill the background pf the custom page with your image.

try out this code

```
var
  Page                 : TWizardPage;
  BackgroundBitmapImage: TBitmapImage;
  s: string;
begin
 Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Custom Page', 'Test');
 ExtractTemporaryFile('background.bmp');
 s:=ExpandConstant('{tmp}')+'\background.bmp';
 BackgroundBitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(Page);
 BackgroundBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(s);
 BackgroundBitmapImage.Parent := Page.Surface;
 BackgroundBitmapImage.Align:=alCLient;
 BackgroundBitmapImage.Stretch:=True; 
end;
```

Comment: thanks, but there is still a quite big margin especially on left side of surface??

Comment: Bit old, but did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

is very nousy to do.
You must split your image in almost 3 piece

```
for WizardForm.MainPanel ( top strip of 60px)
for WizardForm.InnerPage (Center panel around Surface)
for mainPage.Surface (Inside inner Panel)
```

So is a big work of precise cutting....